# Flag removal - feature request

Tags: feature-request, flagging, flags

Could you guys add a feature to unflag a post?  It would be nice to see a list of what you have flagged as, and to be able to remove individual flags.

I know this has happened to many people:  The post requires a flag (which like a good citizen you provide) and an hour later the OP edits to fix it.  Moderators come along and don't like your flag.  Nowhere is there an option to remove a flag after a post has been fixed.

It would also be nice to see who else flags a post and what they flagged it as.

Comment: This has been suggested and asked about many many times (even I have done), but they just don't want to implement it, plus it doesn't really matter because they can easily just decline your flag.